# c++ an array of pointers to a class, initialize to null pionters

Tags: c++, oop

I'm learning c++ and OOP and I have class called "Pion" and I have a class "Chessboard" and in the class "Chessboard" a need to declare a 2d array of pointers to the class "Pion" and initialize it to NULL pointers.

I know how to declare the 2d array but I don't how to initialize it to NULL pointers.

declaring the 2d array should be something like this:
Pion *P[8][8];

but I don't get the set to null pointers part.

Any help/tips are welcome.

[EDIT]

thanks for all the answers/tips but I'm still confused.
so i have a class called Chessboard and I need to create a 2d array of pointers that link to the "Pion" class, this array needs to be a class member and initialize it to NULL pointers.

so I have tried tried out things and I've come up with this

in the .h (header file) I've declared a private member class

Pion *P[8][8];

and within the concstructor I've put this

```
for (int x = 0; x < 8; ++x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 8; ++y) {
        m_velden[x][y] = NULL;
    }
}
```

This seems to be working but i'm not sure if this is the best solution

Comment: How you you go about iterating over the 2D array? Just do the same and set those items to null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on whether P is a local variable or a class member.
In the 1st case, you can initialize all elements to NULL at the moment of declaration

```
Pion *P[8][8] = {};
```

In the 2nd case, use `P()` in the initialization list in `Chessboard` constructor.

Comment: This won't work if `P` is a data member.  If `P` is a data member, you'd need to add `P()` to the initializer list of the class's constructor.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis I agree. It was not obvious from the question if the poster needs a class member.

Answer (score 2):

Several suggestions:  first, multidimensional arrays are rarely worth the hassle in C++; it's probably better to use a single dimensional array, then write a function that takes a row and a column and returns a reference to the element at that logical position.  Single dimensional arrays are simpler to deal with.

Second, it's best to use `std::array` instead of a fixed-size C-style array.  There is no overhead associated with using `std::array` and it provides many free benefits.

Third, you should consider using a smart pointer--for example, `std::unique_ptr<Pion>`--to ensure correct ownership and lifetime management for the dynamically allocated objects, assuming they are dynamically allocated.  (Of course, you should also make sure that you really need to use pointers:  it may suffice, and it would be far simpler, if you can avoid pointers and just store the `Pion` objects in the array, by value.  Whether this makes sense depends on your particular use case.)

With these three suggestions in mind, you might end up with something that looks like:

```
class Chessboard
{
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<Pion>, 64> _pions;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
  for(int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
  {
    P[i][j] = NULL;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to consider is vectors, they're very useful for dynamically adjusting the size of arrays, especially useful for an "array" of classes.